# get list of routes from $routeProvider in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where routes are defined like so:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  'use strict';

  $routeProvider

    .when('/user-management', {
      title: 'Manage: Users',
      permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
      templateUrl: 'views/user-management.html',
      controller: 'UserCtrl'
    })

    .when('/group-management', {
      title: 'Manage: Groups',
      templateUrl: 'views/group-management.html',
      controller: 'GroupManagementCtrl',
      permissions: ['OPERATOR', 'ADMINISTRATOR']
    })
...
```

In a controller I would like to be able to get this route list and also be able to access the permissions for each of the routes. This would be to hide nav elements for pages you don't have permission to.

Is there a good way to get the list of the routes and their associated permissions?

Comment: Why not create an object that contains navigation, permission, and routes, then populate the route provider definition based on that? Then both could reference it, the route provider to build the route and the navigation service to build the menu.

Answer (score 6):

You can access all routes (and additional properties like `permissions`) from `$route.routes`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route.

Excerpt:

```
routes: with all route configuration Objects as its properties.
```